# Can't figure out the Logic here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Well, i came across a piece of code to arranges the numbers in descending order. 
But for every number entered in the list i converted it into string and the output varies and i don't understand how ?

```
def returnString(inputListInt):
    result=''
    inputListStr=[str(x) for x in inputListInt]

    for i in range(len(inputListInt)):
        for j in range(len(inputListInt)-1):
            if (inputListStr[j]<inputListStr[j+1]):
                inputListStr[j], inputListStr[j+1] = inputListStr[j+1], inputListStr[j]
    for i in inputListStr:
        result+=i
    print(result)


if __name__ =="__main__":   
    input = [int(x) for x in input().split(',')]
    returnString(input)
```

So if the input is 5,2,34,7,30,9,6
instead of output being 343097652
it is 976534302

Comment: Because `'9'` > `'34'`.

Comment: Numbers compare numerically, but strings compare lexicographically. `"34" < "5"` for the same reason that `"BA" < "C"`

Comment: thank you austin macha !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because strings are sorted alphabetically and are compared lexicographically.

This gives weird-looking results:

```
'20' < '3' # because the character '3' comes after the character '2'
'540' < '60' # because '6' comes after '5'
```

In the same vein, `'ForceBru' > 'FenceBru'` because `'o' > 'e'` since `'o'` comes after `'e'`.

Comment: so in '34' and '30' it compares '3'first with all other values and if they are equal then it moves to the next character ?

Comment: @joel, it compares `'3' vs '3'`, but they're equal, so it moves on to `'4' vs '0'`. The latter is less, so `'34' > '30'`.